# xmodmapでエラーが出る

Tags: ubuntu

表題の通り、正しいはずの.Xmodmapを実行してもエラーが出てしまいます。

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

.Xmodmapは

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
Keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
```

という内容です。

また、出たエラーは

```
xmodmap:  .Xmodmap:1:  bad keysym in remove modifier list 'Caps_Lock', no corresponding keycodes
xmodmap:  .Xmodmap:2:  bad keysym target keysym 'Caps_Lock', no corresponding keycodes
xmodmap:  2 errors encountered, aborting.
```

となっております。

どのようにすればこのようなエラーが起きなくなるんでしょうか。
ちなみにUbuntub 17.10です

追加情報

```
% xmodmap -pke の結果
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock

% setxkbmap -print の結果
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};

% setxkbmap -query の結果
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
```

Comment: `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape` を実行すると、どうなるでしょうか？

Comment: "keysym Caps_Lock" が現在どの keycode にも割り当てられていないように思います。
"xmodmap -pke" で確認ください。
割り当てられていないのであれば、Xorg や、Gnome などのデスクトップ環境の設定でキーを置き換えているのかもしれません。
"setxkbmap -print", "setxkbmap -query" の情報もあると何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape を実行しても置き換えられませんでした

Answer (score 1):

どうやら最後に実行した`xmodmap`の結果、Caps_Lockがどこにもなくなると`そんなKEYSYMNAMEはkeycodeに割り当てられていないよ(超訳)`と怒られるようです。

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape Caps_Lock
```

とするとうまくいくかもしれません。
[AskUbuntuにあった似たような質問への回答](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23491/how-to-change-capslock-key-to-produce-a)を参考にしました。

Answer (score 0):

"setxkbmap -print", "setxkbmap -query" を見ると、特に options の設定は無いので、デフォルトのままのようです。

"keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock" があるので、特に問題なさそうに見えるのですが、2回実行されているということはありませんでしょうか？
.Xmodmap ではなく、コマンドラインから以下のコマンドを一つずつ実行しても同じエラーメッセージが出ますでしょうか？

```
xmodmap -e 'remove lock = Caps_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'keysym Caps_Lock = Escape'
```